# Adding a Node.js back end to an existing React web app already deployed with Netlify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, backend

What are some good resources to use and read for setting up a Node.js back end for my react application? I have tried searching but there aren't many resources on adding it to an existing project that is deployed with just a front end. I honestly just didn't see a back end coming to my project but now that it is finished, I want to add some features to it which would require a database and a back end.

Curious if there are any suggestions or advice to use. Thank you!

Comment: Really it shouldn't matter what came first. You need to focus on the end result, and add to your project whatever is missing.

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is not qualified to be a valid question since it is not asking about a specific coding/technical problem. It is opinion based. There is a new feature on StackOverflow called "Discussions" and that is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @AlperGüven I don't think asking for resources is a good use of Discussions either

Comment: @AlperGüven The name of this site is written Stack Overflow; two capitalized words with a (non-breaking) space between them. I agree with Bergi.